# Не работает INSER в созданный столбец в Symfony 2.8

Tags: php, symfony2, doctrine

Создал новый столбец с помощью миграций, в него мне надо вставлять данные, но когда проходит запрос, то INSERT этот столбец игнорирует.

**Entity** (здесь добавил свойство и методы get и set skipRating, сделал по примеру работающих метов ниже ):

```
namespace LessonBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Feedback
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="feedback")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="LessonBundle\Repository\FeedbackRepository")
 */
class Feedback
{
    const STATUS_PENDING = 0;
    const STATUS_ACCEPTED = 1;
    const STATUS_REJECTED = 2;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="smallint")
     */
    private $status = self::STATUS_PENDING;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     * @Assert\Range(min=0, max=1)
     * @ORM\Column(name="skip_rating", type="smallint")
     */
    private $skipRating;


    /**
     * Get skipRating
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getskipRating(){
        return $this->skipRating;
    }

    /**
     * Set skipRating
     *
     * @param integer $skipRating
     *
     * @return Feedback
     */
    public function setskipRating($skipRating){

        $this->skipRating = $skipRating;

        return $this;
    }

 //other methods
}
```

**Form** (здесь тоже по аналогу с другими полями):

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
                    ->add('languRating', FeedbackRatingType::class)
                    ->add('lessonRating', FeedbackRatingType::class)
                    ->add('teacherRating', FeedbackRatingType::class)
                    ->add('teacherComment', TextAreaType::class)
                    ->add('skipRating', IntegerType::class)]);
        }
```

**Twig**:

```
<input type="hidden" id="skip_rating_form" name="{{ form.skipRating.vars.full_name }}" value="{{ form.skipRating.vars.value }}" />
```

**Controller**:

```
$feedback = $this->feedbackManager->create();
$feedback->setLesson($lesson);

$form = $this->createForm(FeedbackType::class, $feedback, [
    'languages' => [],
]);

$form->handleRequest($request);
$newFeedback = $form->getData();
$this->feedbackManager->update($newFeedback);
```

И на выходе только вот такой запрос (игнорируя новый столбец все проходит без ошибок):

```
INSERT INTO feedback (status, langu_rating, lesson_rating, teacher_rating, teacher_comment, lesson_comment, created_at, updated_at, lesson_id, language_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84878/discussion-between-dmitry-kozlov-and-vexel).